# Use of no-index-meta-tag on pretty URLs?

Tags: search-engine-indexing, url-rewriting, google-index, noindex, clean-urls

By now I am fighting through the world of SEO and run into a problem, I think.

Let's say I have a page like **www.example.com/i-am-a-pretty-url**, which is re-written by `.htaccess` from `i-am-ugly-url.php` to the above version.

If I now want google to NOT index the pretty url, will it take an effect, if I add `<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />` to the `i-am-ugly-url.php` file?

I think it should, because there is no other way to prevent the indexing of a re-written URL, right?

However I tried this method on some "not-to-index" URLs of mine to remove them from Google index and redirected them to a remove.php, which has the meta-tag no-index in it. I fetched the URLs as Google to crawl these pages quickly multiple times, but there was no effect for days.

If the crawler not consider the meta tag, then every rewritten URL will be indexed, if the crawler finds the page anywhere. If it does and I remove the no-index-tag from the resource file, both URLs - the pretty URL and the file (*.php) will be indexed, if mentioned anywhere.

So how I solve this dilemma?

**UPDATE:**

```
.htaccess sample:
RewriteEngine on
...
...
RewriteRule ^(.*)blog/$ $1artikel.php
...
...
```

thats what I want:
www.example.com/blog/ -> indexed
www.example.com/article.php -> not indexed

Comment: This may be your problem *and redirected them to a remove.php* As well, it takes time for Google to remove a page from the index. Google does want to remove pages as quickly, however, the web is a huge place!!

Comment: @closetnoc So you think it is only a matter of time? In that case, if I no-index my resource-file, does it also affect my pretty URL? If yes, is there a way I can manage it, that my resource file won't be indexed and my pretty-url will?

Comment: Also, you are redirecting the request to another page. It is quite possible that you are telling Google to deindex remove.php and not your pretty URL.

Comment: And how I can solve this problem? If I want to deindex the pretty URL.

Comment: There is a difference between rewrite and redirect. You can rewrite a request and that should work, however, if you use a redirect, a redirect (either 301 or 302) is sent back. Can you post a sample of your .htaccess code?? I will let one of your experts answer. I give 301 redirects or 404s only and do use noindex at all.

Comment: BTW- Hopefully, the up-vote will you get some attention. I am the middle of cooking dinner. ;-) So my attention will be spotty for a while.

Comment: I updated my question: You can now see how I rewrite in my .htaccess. Yes, hopefully^^

Comment: Okay. That is a rewrite. That should be okay. As long as the target page returns the noindex okay. BTW- the Fetch as Google is not exactly what you think it is. It is not the regular googlebot. After a Fetch as Google, it takes one or two days before the regular googlebot visits the page officially. I am thinking you just need to give Google more time. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc Okay, thank you man. And what is, if someone links to www.example.com/article.php ? This URL will be indexed soon, if it is not marked with no-index-meta-tag. Can I prevent this, so that only my pretty URL get indexed?

Comment: That is a good question. Not sure. It is something I will have to face soon enough. My site is just one page with a parameter which creates the page. The update will be all *pretty URLs* that in effect do the same thing as before, access one page with a parameter. It is a catch-22.

Comment: I'd not worry about it, either URL is the same content, users won't care which URL it is. You can also redirect and/or use rel=canonical. Selectively noindexing adds unnecessary complexity & new failure modes.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to set headers when rewriting. This is based [on this Stackoverflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16075317/2343558) and I used it successfully for one of my customer.

An example of implementation would be to set an environement variable while rewriting :

```
RewriteRule PATTERN DESTINATION [ENV=NOINDEX:true]
```

And then treat all requests tagged with this environment variable (`NOINDEX`) to add the `X-Robots-Tag` header:

```
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, follow" env=NOINDEX
```

You can read more information about this header that replaces the meta-tag [on this Google page](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag), but be aware that few search engines might not support it yet.